# Multiple same event samples, noise elimination algorithms?

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, normalization, sample, computational-statistics

In the case where I have multiple samples of the same event, but they are very noisy, thus rather obscuring the curve/trend (or at least making it incredibly ugly and confusing), what is my best bet to clean it up (create a derived data set for the purpose of aiding visualisation/analysis/understanding)?

I figure that since the noise will be different in each sample, it should be possible, at least in theory, to process it together and hugely reduce the problem of smoothing out valid features that any single sample technique would to some degree suffer from.

Are there any particular techniques or algorithms I should consider?

I'm also a little worried that some element of normalisation might be required, if say different samples are the same shape, but with different amplitude, though I'm not sure if this is really a problem or not at the moment.

Comment: Any reason not to just take the mean of your repeated measurements to average out the noise?

Comment: Tried it. Although a slight improvement it was surprisingly ineffective. A smoothing algorithm which can work usefully on multiple samples or something might work too, the ideal result probably would use adjacent as well as parallel data. Complicated though. I found standard smoothing algorithms tended to distort the over all trend/curve by the time they were tuned to a point where they eliminated most noise. Really I wanted advice or direction so I didn't end up adopting algorithms based purely on my aesthetic appreciation of the result, a dangerously unscientific approach...

Comment: I think it will be hard for us to be of much use without knowing more about your data, specific goals, and what you tried already. Perhaps you could edit your post to add more details. Example plots could be useful.